# Lenovo R61i, Windows 7: how to get W-LAN working

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

I've installed a fresh Windows 7 Home Premium using a network cable. Now I'm trying to enable the W-LAN. All drivers which Windows 7 found from itself are installed, in the BIOS W-LAN is enabled, but on the "Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections" the Wireless Network Connection shows a red cross (similar to the not-connected Local Area Connection). Pressing Fn+F5 (there is a blue computer symbol with some wave symbols around it shown) does nothing (the antenna LED on the display near the bluetooth LED remains off and the red cross in the Network Connections remains.

I've installed the W-LAN driver as well as the HotKey-utility from lenovo.com, but the result remains the same.

What further should I install to be able to active the W-LAN? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there seems to be a hardware switch below the left part of the palm rest. After moving it to the right, the W-LAN works now...

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Lenovo ThinkVantage System Update?  It found a missing piece(driver) on my T61 after a WIN7 upgrade and "fixed" the problem hardware easily.  This is a North America link  [ThinkVantage tool](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/tvsu-update.html)

Comment: The WLAN tool installed from this software would have indicated that the card is "turned off"